# Convert from float to integer

Tags: fractions, integers

This may seem like a stupid question but

What method can one use to convert a decimal number, such as $0.672$ into a whole number?

This isn't rounding as $0.999$ should result in $0$, but saying "floor the number" isn't an answer as I'm looking for a mathematical method in which a number, $n$, can be entered and would produce the same result as $floor(n)$.

For those familiar with programming, this is akin to the `int` function in many languages.

As asked in the comments, when given $-0.5$ the result should be $-1$ as it rounds to negative infinity.

**Clarification:** This is not about "what calculator can do what", this is about a mathematical question about a method of calculation. I used a calculator to prevent the smart-arse answers I usually get when I ask questions, not as something you can base your answer on.

Comment: *a calculator, which cannot understand "look for the number in from of the decimal point"* – What can it understand then? "Look at the sign"? "Check if it overflows"? What operations can it perform? Modulo? Tangent? Is there a memory to store intermittent results? Or can I at least write them down elsewhere? How is the number entered? By typing? If so, the straightforward way is to make the calculator ignore digits after a dot when they are pressed.

Comment: What would you do to $-0.5$? Would it be $-1$ or $0$?

Comment: I presume you mean with a very basic calculator (all calculators I owned in the last 4 decades have had a fractional part operator)?

Comment: This sounds like a nonmathematical question: "how is a float stored in bits and how might the integer part be obtained on a particular calculator" is a question about a particular implementation, and depends on the calculator!

Answer (score 1):

As a programmer, given a float called `f`, what I would do is

```
int floor( float f ) {
    float r = f % 1;
    return = f - r;
}
```

In English, you find the portion that is less than 1 by doing a modulus operation, and then subtract that amount. This only works with positive numbers; not sure if this works on negative numbers, and if it doesn't, how to handle them. The function above should probably check for values less than zero and return and error.

Comment: If the mod operation on negative numbers returns the number closer to zero, just subtract 1 to round toward negative infinity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're out of luck. The function you want is just plain **floor**, defined by 
$$
\text{floor}(x) = \text{ greatest integer less than or equal to } x
$$

There is no other

> mathematical method in which a number, $n$, can be entered and would
>   produce the same result as $\text{floor}(n)$.

As @scott points out in his answer, you can compute the floor if you extend the definition of the modulus operator as some computer languages do. But that's essentially just wrapping the floor function.